# How should I call the script that starts my project in my package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, server

If I have a Node.js project and want to create a script that does: `nodemon server.js`, is there any convention for calling this script? I usually call it `dev` but just wanted to know if there's any specific convention.

Comment: `dev` probably is the best practice as `nodemon` shouldn't really be used in production, and it's used for development hot-reloading. If anything, you should keep a name that makes the most sense for that project.

Answer (score 1):

You looking for `start`?

```
"scripts": {
            "start": "nodemon server.js",
            "dev": "nodemon server.js"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts" : {"start:dev": "nodemon server.js"}
```

I think you are using the same. and it is the best practice.